# .htaccessでの別ページへのリダイレクト

Tags: .htaccess

以下の旧URLに来た場合、301リダイレクトで新URLへ転送したいのですが、
.htaccessのRewriteRuleはどのように書けばいいでしょうか? いろいろ試していますが、
うまくいきません。アドバイスいただければ幸いです。

旧URL `https://example.com/stay/db/database.cgi?cmd=dp&num=1234&dp=ad.html`
新URL `https://example.com/stay/db/database.cgi?cmd=dp&num=1234&dp=all.html`

【条件追記】上記新旧URLに書きました「1234」という部分は、実は複数あるうちの一つでして、他に「2354」になったURLもあります。この数字が「1234」の時だけリダイレクトしたいのです。

【テスト結果】

URLが新URLへリダイレクトされましたが、以下のエラー画面が出て、

「このページは動作していません 「ドメイン名」でリダイレクトが繰り返し行われました。Cookie を消去してみてください.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS」

新URL https://example.com/stay/db/database.cgi?cmd=dp&num=1234&dp=all.html
の画面が表示されなくなりました。(代わりに上記エラー画面が出ます)
(Cookie を消去してみましたが同じで上記エラー画面が出ます)

【成功しました】

1234があるとリダイレクトし続けるようなので、以下のようにしましたら無事成功しました。

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/stay/db/database.cgi?cmd=dp&num=1234&dp=all.html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &num=1234&dp=ad.html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&dp)=(.+)$

RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%1=all.html [R=301,L]

アドバイスありがとうございました。感謝です。
上記結果で、何か不備がありましたら、ご教示をよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: その`いろいろ試していますが`の部分を質問文に追記できますでしょうか？どこに認識違いや、間違いがあるか具体的に指摘がしやすくなります。

Comment: 質問文に記載のものでも問題は無いと思います。もう少し短めのものを回答に追記しておきました。もし、解決したようでしたら回答横のチェックマークを選択して回答を承認してください。そうすると質問が解決済みになります。また、自己回答も出来ますので、もし問題があれば解決した内容を自己回答してください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これで通じますかね？
また、恐らくサンプルURLだとおもいますが、構造が全く同じであればこれでいけると思います。
一度試して、問題が無ければ`R=301`へ変更してください。

---

**追記**
基本的に条件が増えた場合は`RewriteCond`を増やせば問題ありません。
また、質問文を見て他の人が回答できるように質問してください。
質問する際は次のページが参考になります。
[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

(同ページにリダイレクトした場合にall.htmlは除外する条件を追加）

```
# Rewriteモジュールが導入されている場合のみ処理
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # Rewriteモジュールを有効化
  RewriteEngine on
  # 条件定義1
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(&dp=all.html)$
  # 条件定義2
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &num=1234&
  # 条件定義3
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&dp)=(.+)$
  # プロトコル + ホスト名 + リクエストURI + 定義した条件グループの1つ目 + 固定値
  RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%1=all.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: 条件を質問文に追記しました。他の条件はありません。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @makapapa 回答を追記しました。